# internal path length algorithm binary tree

Tags: recursion, trees, binary, stability-in-odes, data-structure

I need an algorithm (if it's in C # it would be perfect) that calculates the internal path length of a binary tree. I have searched all over the internet and I can't find anything, please help me urgently (sorry for the mistakes, I'm not a native English speaker, I'm using a translator).

Comment: Why don't you come up with one?

Comment: I've tried to do it on my own, but I don't know where to start